# Find the parametric curver from points (2,1) and (5,4)

Tags: calculus, parametric

I already found $x=2+3t$ and $y=1+3t$ but I don't know how to get the whole equation of $r(t)=$? and what the boundaries are $?<t<?$

Comment: I'm confused. How could you arrive at the equations $x=2+3t$ and $y=1+3t$ without considering boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

You're done. Or maybe you want to write
$$
r(t) = (2 + 3t, 1 + 3t), 0 \le t \le 1,
$$
to make it a little more complete.